# What is the term for color overlay effect?

Tags: color, terminology, lighting-effects

Is there a specific term for this type of color/light effect overlay? If so, what is it?

*a user suggest 'gradient mesh'* However I am not quiet sure with this as it does not come up in Google accurately.

[image]
[image]

Comment: Hi LordSacha, are you trying to find multi-colored gradients like the semi-transparent square over the iphone screen? Probably something like "gradient mesh background" or "multi gradient background". Why not just make the backgrounds? You could just paint with a soft brush and then blur the image to smooth out the transition of colors.

Comment: Yes. This is a screenshit from an app. The circle below are 100 alpha effect and the square overlay is 40 alpha. And yes I am looking for the proper term of this technique if there is any.

Comment: What exactly are you looking to download? They just look like gradients, unless I'm missing something (I don't quite understand what's going on in that screenshot so I may be)

Comment: It was gradient used as photo color effect/lighting effect by overlaying them. I am looking for the term for this technique so that i can search on google, etc.

Comment: I'm still not sure what you are looking to download. All they are, are gradients used as filters or overlays. It's not something you can download, you either have an app that does this (which it looks like you already have) or you could download or create some gradients and search for techniques for using them as overlays or filters (most likely just using blending modes and transparency).

Comment: Ok, so you are saying there is no technical term for this type of gradient overlay?

Answer (score 1):

That would be a type of [gradient overlay](https://www.google.com/search?q=gradient+overlays&tbm=isch), a [light leak](https://www.google.com/search?q=light+leak&tbm=isch). :)

Comment: Is that term more proper than 'light leaks'?

Comment: I would say that a light leak is a specific type of gradient overlay (closer to what you meant!) and have updated my answer accordingly.

Comment: ...  Fine by me.. as long as some senior endorsed it. I am, you know, a newbie in this design dimension.